# CasperJS not finding file that is clearly there

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

This actually originally generated from a problem I was having running SpookyJS, but managed to nail it down to a problem with the underlying CasperJS (and based on another stackoverflow question I was directed to, possibly even a PhantomJS problem).

We determined that the command CasperJS was failing on was:

```
casperjs C:\wwwroot\dra\node_modules\spooky\lib\bootstrap.js --spooky_lib=C:\wwwroot\dra\node_modules\spooky\lib\ --command=casperjs --port=8081 --transport=stdio
```

Which generates the following:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"emit","params":["error","CasperError: CasperJS couldn't find module C:\\wwwroot\\dra\\node_modules\\spooky\\lib\\bootstrap\\stdio-server",[{"file":"C:\\casperjs\\n1k0-casperjs-bc0da16\\batchbin\\..\\bin\\bootstrap.js","line":133,"function":"_require"},{"file":"C:\\wwwroot\\dra\\node_modules\\spooky\\lib\\bootstrap.js","line":34,"function":""}]]}
```

At first I thought the fact that it was generating double slashes was an issue, but I've since learned that that's simply the way it spits it out.  It simply can't find the file.  I've tried to reference the file a few different ways, but to no avail. And, yes, the file is most definitely there. It's looking for stdio-server.js which is exactly where it's looking for it.  It's also not specific to this file.  In the course of my testing, I commented out that line and it failed three lines later, in the same fashion, looking for a different file.

I'm using:
CasperJS 1.0.2
PhantomJS 1.9.0

I'm desperate to get this working (preferably today since I have to demo it to my boss), so if anyone has any input on this I'd be MOST appreciative!

Thank you.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what is your goal?

Comment: If hexid's answer (of upgrading to 1.9.1) solved the problem, can you give it the correct answer tick (and upvote would be polite too); or if not, please let us know what did solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix this by upgrading PhantomJS to 1.9.1

Here are links to the [CasperJS issue](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/429) and the [PhantomJS issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11165) regarding this problem.